# Rails 3 Action Mailer view file naming convention

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

In the api guide I see the naming convention to be:

```
mail.text.html.erb
mail.text.plain.erb
```

[api guide](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html)

But in the edgeguides the convention is:

```
mail.html.erb
mail.text.erb
```

[edge guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html)

Which is the preferred way?

Comment: The latter one is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

The second one, I believe. Try it.